# Explain to me how config works in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config

I have a Rails 3 application, call it "MyApp". In my config\environments\production.rb file I see such things as

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.log_level = :info
  config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first, 'daily')
   ...or...
  config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log",Rails.env + ".log"),3,20*1024*1024)
```

So, questions are focusing on terminology and wtf they mean... (or point me to some site ,I have looked but not found, to explain how this works.)

1. MyApp is a module?
2. MyApp::Application is a ...? What, a module too?
3. MyApp::Application.configure is a method?
4. config is a variable? How do I see it in console?
5. config.logger is a ???
6. config.paths.log.first is a ...??
   --in console I can see "MyApp::Application.configure.config.paths.log.first" but don't know what that means or how to extract info from it!?!

Is this too much for one question? :)

I have looked at the tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html but it jumps right into what things do.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A six sided question! Oh my. Let's *ahem* roll.<sup>1</sup> Here's hoping I receive 6 times the upvotes for it then? :)

**1. MyApp is a module?**

Yes, it's a module. It acts as a "container" for all things pertaining to your application. For instance you could define a class like this:

```
module MyApp
  class MyFunClass
    def my_fun_method
    end
  end
end
```

Then if someone else has a `MyFunClass`, it won't interfere with your `MyFunClass`. It's just a nice way of separating out the code.

**2. MyApp::Application is a ...? What, a module too?**

`MyApp::Application` is actually a class, which inherits from `Rails::Application`. This does a quite a lot of things, including setting up the `Rails.application` object which is actually an instance of `MyApp::Application` that you can do all sorts of fun things on like making requests to your application (in a `rails console` or `rails c` session). This code for instance would make a dummy request to the root path of your application, returning a 3-sized Array which is just a plain Rack response:

```
 Rails.application.call(Rack::MockRequest.env_for("/"))
```

You can also get the routes for your application by calling this:

```
 Rails.application.routes
```

The main *purpose* of defining `MyApp::Application` is not these fun things that you'll probably never use, but rather so that you can define application-specific configuration inside `config/application.rb`. Things like what parameters are filtered, the time zone of the application or what directories should be autoloaded. These are all covered in the [Configuration Guide for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

**3. MyApp::Application.configure is a method?**

Indeed it is a method, and it allows you to add further configuration options to your application's configuration after `config/application.rb` has been loaded. You've probably seen this used in `config/environments/development.rb` or one of the other two files in that directory, but basically they all use the same options as shown in that [Configuration Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) linked to earlier.

**4. config is a variable? How do I see it in console?**

The `config` "variable" is actually a method defined within the code used for `Rails::Application` and returns quite simply a configuration object which stores the configuration for the application.

To access it in the console, just use `Rails.application.config`. This will return quite a large `Rails::Application::Configuration` object for your viewing pleasure.

**5. config.logger is a ???**

The method you're referring to, I assume, comes from this line in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
# Use a different logger for distributed setups
# config.logger = SyslogLogger.new
```

The method in this example is not `config.logger`, but rather `config.logger=`, which is referred to as a "setter" method in Ruby-land. The one without the equal sign is referred to as a "getter". This method sets up an alternative logger for the production environment in Rails, which then can be accessed by using `Rails.logger` within the console or the application itself.

This is useful if you want to output something to the logs, as you can simply call this code:

```
Rails.logger.info("DEBUG INFO GOES HERE")
```

**6. config.paths.log.first is a ...?? --in console I can see "MyApp::Application.configure.config.paths.log.first" but don't know what that means or how to extract info from it!?!**

Within a Rails application, you can modify the locations of certain directories. And so, this `config.paths` method is a way of keeping track of where these directories map to. In my entire Rails life I have never had to use or modify this variable and that can mean either one of two things:

1. It's not used often by Rails programmers, or;
2. I don't live a very varied life.

Interpret it as you will. My main point is that you're probably never going to use it either.

---

I hope these help you understand Rails a little more!

<sup>1</sup> Terrible dice joke.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have things working but get restless and want to know more wtf is going on. Many thanks, the more I know the better I like it.

Comment: @rtfminc: Glad to help! It was a very fun question to answer :)

Answer (score 6):

- `MyApp` is a module, it's a namespace including an app you'll launch, see next line
- `MyApp::Application` is a Class and you're running it's instances when running a Rails app
- `MyApp::Application.configure` is a method. It passes all instructions to the class. [See Ref.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.6/railties/lib/rails/application.rb)
- `config` is a method or an instance variable (when set) which belongs through inheritance to `Rails::Application::Configuration`. [See Ref.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.6/railties/lib/rails/application/configurable.rb)

You can see it in console doing: `MyApp::Application.config`

- `config.logger` doesn't exist until you define it, so it's a Logger instance. [See Ref.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.6/railties/lib/rails.rb)
- `config.paths.log` is a `Rails::Paths::Path`

you can access it in console using:  `MyApp::Application.config.paths.log`